iterm Actions Dropdown
I am using the iterm status bar with the Actions Menu to store common bash commands that I use, but my list is growing and it would be great to organize these in a hierarchy. Is there anything that exists?
For example my actions menu looks like this:
K8 Context (Does nothing)
... Switch to context foo
... Switch to context bar
Sync Database
Deploy (Does nothing)
... Run script x
... Run script y

I would like to have (Does nothing) open a submenu
